# How to run Google AppScript exclusively?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I have build a Google AppScript code which uses Google Forms, Google Sheet and Gmail. This is used to select specific slides based on slide numbers and send an email with a customised slide deck. I have set a trigger where the appscript runs on form submit. However when multiple user submit the form at the same time - they appscript runs into errors and does not finish running as a result does not send emails to the users. I presume this is happening because of overload of request on the trigger. Is there an alternative way to do this without overloading the script whilst completing the script each time the form is submitted.

Please see below code sample from the project (some field names have been replaced with xxx however the underlying concept remains the same),

```
function xxx() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master").activate();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow()

  for (var i =2;i<lr;i++){

    if(ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue()){  

  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('FileID').makeCopy().getId(); //Make a copy of the template file


      var Name_of_programme = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
      var xxx = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue().split(", ");
      var xxx = ss.getRange(i, 8).getValue().split(", ");

  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(Name_of_programme); //Renaming the google slides

  var FileName = Name_of_programme;  //Capturing the file name as a variable to be used in Email

  //Get the document body as a variable
  var body = SlidesApp.openById(documentId);

      var slides = body.getSlides();
      var slideNumber = 1;
      var slideURL = body.getUrl()+"#slide=id."+slides[slideNumber-1].getObjectId();
  ss.getRange(i, 34).setValue(slideURL);

      //Start email variables
      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 33).getValue();
      var subjectLine = "Slide has been drafted";
      var templateText =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{FileName}", FileName).replace("{slideURL}", slideURL);

      //Start setting presentation variables
      var Master_presentation = SlidesApp.openById(documentId);
      var Selection_presentation = SlidesApp.openById('SlideID');
      var Course_outlines_presentation = SlidesApp.openById('SlideID');
      var Trainer_profile_presentation = SlidesApp.openById('SlideID');

  var offset = 0;
  var page = 0;

      //For each variable set new variables to get slides

      if(Country_credentials != ""){
        var Country_credentials_slides = Selection_presentation.getSlides();
        Country_credentials.forEach(function(p, i) {
        Master_presentation.appendSlide(Country_credentials_slides[p - 1]);
        })
      } else {
      };

      if(Value_adds != ""){
        var Value_adds_slides = Selection_presentation.getSlides();
        Value_adds.forEach(function(t, i) {
        Master_presentation.appendSlide(Value_adds_slides[t - 1]);
        })
      } else {
      };

      if(Digital_course_outlines != ""){
        var Digital_course_outlines_slides = Course_outlines_presentation.getSlides();
        Digital_course_outlines.forEach(function(u, i) {
        Master_presentation.appendSlide(Digital_course_outlines_slides[u - 1]);
        })
      } else {
      };


      var Trainer_template_slides1 = Trainer_profile_presentation.getSlides()[0];
      Master_presentation.appendSlide(Trainer_template_slides1);  

      var Trainer_template_slides2 = Trainer_profile_presentation.getSlides()[1];
      Master_presentation.appendSlide(Trainer_template_slides2); 

      var Trainer_template_slides3 = Trainer_profile_presentation.getSlides()[2];
      Master_presentation.appendSlide(Trainer_template_slides3); 

      if(Client_success_story != ""){
        var Behavioural_trainer_profiles_slides = Trainer_profile_presentation.getSlides();
        Behavioural_trainer_profiles.forEach(function(z, i) {
        Master_presentation.appendSlide(Behavioural_trainer_profiles_slides[z - 1]);
        })
      } else {
      };


  var Final_slide = Selection_presentation.getSlides()[49];
  Master_presentation.appendSlide(Final_slide);    

  //Replace all placeholders

      body.replaceAllText('[xxx]', xxx);
      body.replaceAllText('[xxx]', xxx);


  MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody);

       }
    else {}
    }
  }
```

Let me know if you would like to see how the sheet looks like to further understand the scenario. Maybe there is a better way of coding and different logic to be used in what I want to achieve.

Comment: You'll need to use the [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)

Comment: could you guide me on how to best implement lock service in this code?